# Desktop.exe in Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop

I have installed ubuntu on my laptop and Desktop. But I need to access another window installed PC/Server using remotedesktop.exe. How can I open remote desktop . exe in Ubuntu for accessing another window installed PC/Server? Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

By Default there is a Software in Ubuntu, Remmina Remote Desktop Client Use it

Comment: The problem is My client has sent me Remote desktop.exe file . When I open it on windows it shows me only the Domain name and then after updating username and pw I get access to the server. So in Ubuntu for the same access. I update the domain name and then my username and PW. But unable to access the server. So I just installed "Wine" on Ubuntu and then tried to access but it gives me an error message ...